# How to find a substring from a string?

Tags: split, apache-pig

Lets say my string is like this "20136 asjd". I only want the first part - "20136" - and I want to use this string as a `group by` for further process. How do I achieve this in Pig?

I am trying with this approch:

```
A = load 'file.txt';
B = group A by strsplit(mystring,' ');
```

But I only want the first part of that string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
STRSPLIT generates tuple. To convert that tuple into atoms you need to apply FLATTEN.
Just apply flatten to STRSPLIT function and then take the first part.

input :

```
  (20136 asjd)
```

Code:

```
 A = load 'file.txt' USING PigStorage() as (mystring:chararray); 
 B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(mystring,'')) as(a1,a2);
 C = GROUP B BY a1:
```

Then you can  do anything you want ..

Just explore More about STRSPLIT and FLATTEN combination, you will get more..

Hope this helps!!